# How to edit the implode so it will join values with two strings?

Tags: php, function, implode

In the function below a possible output maybe

```
1 day and 2 hours and 34 minutes
```

My question is how do I edit the implode so it will output

```
1 day, 2 houts and 34 minutes
```

This is my function

```
function time_difference($endtime){
    $hours = (int)date("G",$endtime);
    $mins = (int)date("i",$endtime);

    // join the values
    $diff = implode(' and ', $diff);

    if (($hours == 0 ) && ($mins == 0)) {
        $diff = "few seconds ago";
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
if ($days) {
    $diff .= "$days day";
    $diff .= $days > 1 ? "s" : "";
}
if ($hours) {
    $diff .= $diff ? ", " : "";
    $diff .= "$hours hour";
    $diff .= $hours > 1 ? "s" : "";
}
if ($mins) {
    $diff .= $diff ? " and " : "";
    $diff .= "$mins minute";
    $diff .= $mins > 1 ? "s" : "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function implodeEx($glue, $pieces, $glueEx = null)
{
    if ($glueEx === null)
        return implode($glue, $pieces);
    $c = count($pieces);
    if ($c <= 2)
        return implode($glueEx, $pieces);

    $lastPiece = array_pop($pieces);
    return implode($glue, array_splice($pieces, 0, $c - 1)) . $glueEx . $lastPiece;
}

$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
echo implodeEx(',', $a, ' and ');
```

Comment: I changed this `$diff = implode(' and ', $diff);` to `$diff = implodeEX(' and ', $diff);` but didn't make any difference

Comment: @mtopia Have you tried looking at GolezTrol's example how he calls it? This is it: `implodeEx(',', $a, ' and ')`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places for x-time-ago functions. [here](http://discusstech.org/2011/02/create-twitter-facebook-style-x-time-ago-date-format-in-php/) are [two](http://www.snilesh.com/resources/php/twitter-facebook-like-time-difference-using-php/) in PHP. Here's [one](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you but I want to stick with what I have. (I tried both PHP, none worked for me)