# Adding a character before last word in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, implode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implode array with “, ” and add “and ” before last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item)

In Wordpress, I am using PHP implode to separate a series of strings with commas, that are stored in an array like so:

Wordpress Loop Iterates through this:

```
<?php unset($credits); ?>
<?php if(get_field('song_credits')):
    while(has_sub_field('song_credits')): 
       $credits[] = get_sub_field('artist_name');
    endwhile; ?>
    <p><?php echo implode(', ', $credits); ?>.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, a series of strings is stored into the $credits array, and then I use implode to separate each string with a comma.

I need to add an ampersand right before the last word instead of a comma. Is this possible here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`implode` cannot do this directly, but it's not that difficult:

```
switch (count($credits)) {
    case 0:
        $result = '';
        break;
    case 1:
        $result = reset($credits);
        break;
    default:
        $last = array_pop($credits); // warning: this modifies the array!
        $result = implode(', ', $credits).' & '.$last;
        break;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me, but the following does:  <p><?php echo join(' and ', array_filter(array_merge(array(join(', ', array_slice($credits, 0, -1))), array_slice($credits, -1)))); ?></p>

Comment: the above was taken from:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item

Comment: @JCHASE11: It would have [worked for you](http://ideone.com/tlfBu) if you had bothered to test it.

Comment: I actually did test it before writing my response. But because it does in fact work, I will give you the correct answer...no need to get testy....Thanks.

Comment: btw, the above was a pun, not a criticism!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [Implode array with ", " and add "and " before last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item)

`<p><?php echo join(' and ', array_filter(array_merge(array(join(', ', array_slice($credits, 0, -1))), array_slice($credits, -1)))); ?></p>`

this works just great