# PHP Checkbox multiple implodes

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes, lets say;

```
<input type="checkbox" value='One' />
<input type="checkbox" value='Two' />
<input type="checkbox" value='Three' />
```

My php looks like;

```
echo implode(', ', get_field('checkboxes'));
```

When I check all the boxes my output looks like;

> One, Two, Three

But, I am looking for a way my output looks like;

> One, Two & Three

And when I check only two boxes the output will be;

> One & Two

Can't find this anywhere, please help!

Cheers

Comment: Show us the `get_field` code

Comment: I'm working with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin on Wordpress. Therefore I call get_field.

Comment: this definitely helps:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have an array of values, you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) to pick only a certain part of an array to make the implode, and then complement with the last `&`. Here's a function of example:

```
function show_values($values) {
    $size = count($values);

    $text = implode(', ', array_slice($values, 0, -1));
    $text .= ($size > 1) ? ' & ' : '';
    $text .= $values[$size - 1];

    return $text;
}

echo show_values(array('One')) . "\n"; // One
echo show_values(array('One', 'Two')) . "\n"; // One & Two
echo show_values(array('One', 'Two', 'Three')) . "\n"; // One, Two & Three
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
$checkboxes = get_field('checkboxes');

$output = '';
$length = count($checkboxes);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if($i < $length - 1) {
        $output .= $checkboxes[$i] . ', '; 
        continue;
    }

    $output .= '& ' . $checkboxes[$i];
}

echo $output;
```