# Imploding with "and" in the end?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kanal] => TV3+
            [image] => 3Plus-Logo-v2.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kanal] => 6\'eren
            [image] => 6-eren.png
        )  
    [2] => Array
        (
            [kanal] => 5\'eren
            [image] => 5-eren.png
        )

)
```

It may expand to several more subarrays.

How can I make a list like: `TV3+, 6'eren and 5'eren`?

Comment: `foreach`, `if`, `count` ?

Comment: that is what im thinking as well @zerkms

Comment: @zerkms - what's the count for ;)

Comment: As i see it, you only need foreach.

Comment: @blue: how would you know which element is last to switch between `, ` and `and` ?  /cc @Y U NO WORK

Comment: What is your final expected output ?

Comment: @Rikesh it is `TV3+, 6'eren and 5'eren`

Answer (score 4):

As array could potentially be to further depths, you would be best off using a recursive function such as [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

```
$result = array();

array_walk_recursive($inputArray, function($item, $key) use (&$result) {

    array_push($result, $item['kanal']);
}
```

To then convert to a comma separated string with 'and' separating the last two items

```
$lastItem = array_pop($result);

$string = implode(',', $result);

$string .= ' and ' . $lastItem;
```

Comment: What about the `and` stuff

Answer (score 3):

Took some time but here we go,

```
$arr = array(array("kanal" => "TV3+"),array("kanal" => "5\'eren"),array("kanal" => "6\'eren"));
$arr =  array_map(function($el){ return $el['kanal']; }, $arr);
$last = array_pop($arr);
echo $str = implode(', ',$arr) . " and ".$last;
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/i6g4KQ)**.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go ,

```
$myarray =  array(
                    array(
                            'kanal' => 'TV3+',
                            'image' => '3Plus-Logo-v2.png'
                          ),
                    array(
                            'kanal' => '6\'eren',
                            'image' => '6-eren.png'
                          ),
                    array(
                            'kanal' => '5\'eren',
                            'image' => '5-eren.png'
                          ),

                    );

foreach($myarray as $array){
    $result_array[] = $array['kanal'];
}

$implode = implode(',',$result_array);

$keyword = preg_replace('/,([^,]*)$/', ' & \1', $implode);

echo $keyword;
```

Comment: What if some `$array['kanal']` contains a comma character?

Answer (score 2):

if you simply pass in the given array to implode() function,you can't get even the value of the subarray.
[see this example](http://3v4l.org/VU8LM)

assuming your array name $arr,codes are below

```
   $length = sizeof ( $arr );
   $out = '';
   for($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i ++) {
       $out .= $arr [$i] ['kanal'] . ', ';
   }
   $out .= ' and ' . $arr [$length - 1] ['kanal'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work to you:

```
$data = array(
    0 =>['kanal' => 'TV1+'],
    1 =>['kanal' => 'TV2+'],
    2 =>['kanal' => 'TV3+'],
);
        $output = '';
        $size = sizeof($data)-1;
        for($i=0; $i<=$size; $i++) {
             $output .= ($size == $i && $i>=2) ? ' and ' : '';
             $output .= $data[$i]['kanal'];
             $output .= ($i<$size-1) ? ', ' : '';
        }

echo $output;

//if one chanel:
// TV1
//if two chanel:
// TV1 and TV2
//if three chanel:
// TV1, TV2 and TV3
//if mote than three chanel:
// TV1, TV2, TV3, ... TV(N-1) and TV(N)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$last  = array_slice($array, -1);
$first = join(', ', array_slice($array, 0, -1));
$both  = array_filter(array_merge(array($first), $last));
echo join(' and ', $both);
```

Code is "stolen" from here: [Implode array with ", " and add "and " before last item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    echo ", ".$arr['kanal'];
}
?>
```

Comment: code only answer is not recommended in stackoverflow. Could you please explain your answer.