# Swift - How do I create a string from array of objects that have String property?

Tags: ios, swift, string

How do I create a string from array of objects that have String property?

```
class Person {
   let name: String
}

let people = [Person(name: "Sam"), Person(name: "Zoey"), Person(name: "Bil")]

let peopleNames: String = //what should be here?

peopleNames = "Sam, Zoey, Bil"
```

Comment: Did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36488506/2323806

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan That is pretty outdated isn't it? It looks like Swift 2.

Comment: @Sweeper, agreed! At least could get the HINT from the same, and your answer is updated one ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an array of Ints to a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774352/convert-an-array-of-ints-to-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you want `"Sam, Zoey, Bil"` as your result?

In that case, you can do this:

```
people.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: ", ")
```

We first transform all the people to just their names, then call `joined` which joins all the strings together.