# determining last loop so that comma is not added

Tags: php

I am not sure if I need to determine the last loop or if there is a better way to do this. But I am trying to generate a list of items within square brackets and the last item can't have a comma.

Here is my code:

```
content_ids: ["<?php  for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products_array); $i<$n; $i++) {echo $products_array[$i]['id'].',';} ?>"]
```

So this would print:

```
content_ids: ["1,2,3,"]
```

The last comma after 3 should not be there.

Comment: try using implode function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about trying this

```
content_ids: ["<?php

for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products_array); $i<$n; $i++) {

    if($i == ($n-1)){
        echo $products_array[$i]['id']; 
    }else{
        echo $products_array[$i]['id'].','; 
    };

};

?>"]
```

Comment: I think this will work however there are other items in the array and I only want the "id" I tried this but it does not work with implode because it is a single value: for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products_array); $i<$n; $i++) {
 echo implode( ",", $products_array[$i]['id'] );

}

Comment: ok I edited the above code - you just need to check for the last item as `$i == ($n-1)`

Comment: Ya this works perfect. I do feel like I should have been able to do it with implode like you originally thought. But this will work:)

Comment: To use Implode you would need to array_pop the last item off, implode and then add it back on - see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to accomplish this in one single line:

```
$products_array = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3,
  ),
);
echo '["'.implode(',',array_column($products_array, 'id')).'"]';
// Displays ["1,2,3"]
```