# How to replace string with an array() in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have a text like this,

```
$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [another_name] and [one_another_name]";
```

And an array like this,

```
$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");
```

Now, how can I replace the texts between braces by following array?

I want a result like this,

```
I have some fruits like Banana, Apple and Orange.
```

Please provide the actual solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: @tanmoy-dutta - possible DUPLICATE. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586141/implode-array-with-and-add-and-before-last-item#answer-25057951

Comment: Thanks @Sudhir Ojha for your suggestion. But sorry to say that I didn't found in that post what actually I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)  with a regex [`\[[^]]+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/k2Xp4G/1) to match an opening `[`, then match not a `]` using a negated character class and then match `]`.

In the callback use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to shift an element off the beginning of the array and use that as the replacement.

```
$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [another_name] and [one_another_name]";
$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[[^]]+\]/',
    function ($matches) use (&$fruits_array) {
        return array_shift($fruits_array);
    },
    $string
);

echo $string;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KVqae)

Comment: @TanmoyDutta I have changed my answer to `preg_replace_callback` because the previous will not work when there already is `%s` present in the string.

Comment: Thanks @TheFourthBird

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [another_name] and [one_another_name]";
$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");

foreach($fruits_array as $replace)
{
    $string = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/i', $replace, $string, 1);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: sorry it was by mistake

Comment: Elegant approch base on regex. Nice pruposal

Comment: If we give fullstop `.` at the end, output is getting weird.

Comment: Thanks you all. But sorry to say that it's not working. Do you have any alternative idea?

Comment: Do you have different code? If you have then post it, I already tried my answer and its successful

Comment: Please provide the solution if my string will be like this,

$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [another_name] and [one_another_name]";

As I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [name] and [name]";

$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");

foreach ($fruits_array as $key => $value) {
  $string = preg_replace('[name]', $value, $string, 1);
}
$string = str_replace('[', '', $string);
$string = str_replace(']', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode the array by comma with space. Try like this :

```
$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");

echo 'I have some fruits like '.implode(', ',$fruits_array).'.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$string = "I have some fruits like [name], [name] and [name]";
$arr = explode('[name]',$string);
$fruits_array = array("Banana", "Apple", "Orange");

$newText = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
   $newText .= $arr[$i] . $fruits_array[$i];
}

echo $newText;
```